# Integrate Jasper in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jasper-reports

I'm trying to integrate a **rails 3** app with **jasper** following this wiki:

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoIntegrateJasperReports

But it seems that a lot of information isn't updated so it's been very hard to make it work by myself. I've also read a topic at **ruby-forum**: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139453
with some details explained but still couldn't make it work.

My first problem is related with the render_to_string method: 
When the controller method runs I receive a "Template is missing" error:

this is the method:

```
def report
  @customers = Customer.all
  send_doc(render_to_string(:template => report_customers_path, :layout => false), '/pdfs', 'report.jasper', "customers", 'pdf')
end
```

Although this seems simple I'm not understanding why is this happening. Doesn't **render_to_string** with **layout => false** suposed to get me the string result of that action?
I also tried **:action** instead of **:template**, but it does the same.

If anybody with some expertise with this integration could help...
Thanks in advance,
André

Comment: Are you running on ruby or jruby?

Comment: ruby -v = ruby 1.9.2p180

Comment: What is the missing template error?

Comment: And can you post your send_doc method please.

Comment: I tried to review the project and now even the wiki page is blank. Somebody erased the content.

Answer (score 1):

We actually use jasperreports to create reports, and recently upgraded to Rails 3.0. To create the xml, we use xml.erb templates. Jasper reports runs in a separate glassfish server Here's the general idea:

```
url = URI.parse(my_url_string)
dataxml = render_to_string(:template => my_template_name).gsub(/\n/, '')
params = {'type' => 'pdf', 'compiledTemplateURI' => my_jasper_file, 'data' => dataxml }
request = Net::HTTP::POST.new(url.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)
obj = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
obj.read_timeout = my_timeout_setting
response = obj.start { |http| http.request(request) }
case response
when Net::HTTPOK
  send_data(response.body, :filename => my_chosen_filename, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline")
else
  raise "failed to generate report"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about jasper, but it sounds like you want to do two things: render a PDF template and then send the raw output back w/ a PDF mime type:

```
pdf_contents = render_to_string(:template => 'users/report')

send_data(pdf_contents, :file_name => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf')
```

You're passing in the external URL as the template path, but that's probably wrong if you're getting errors about the template path.  Fix the template path first.

Comment: That method was based on the wiki but somebody deleted the content of the wiki page ( link @ 3rd line). You can see it now at http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoIntegrateJasperReports

Comment: I think Winfield is right, you should change your template value to something like 'customer/report' (like the example on that link) instead of a path method. Or just take out that option altogether and render_to_string should be able to figure out that you want to render the report view. just make sure you have the right "format" extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `render_to_string()` code to this:

```
@customers.to_xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use savon to interact with jaserserver in rails3.
Here is an example:

```
require 'logger'
require 'savon'

logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.info "Test jasper via Savon-SOAP"

@client = Savon::Client.new {
  wsdl.document = "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/services/repository?wsdl"
  http.auth.basic "jasperadmin", "jasperadmin"
}

logger.info "runReport method"
begin
  result = @client.request :run_report do
   soap.body = "<requestXmlString>
     <![CDATA[
      <request operationName='runReport' >
       <argument name='RUN_OUTPUT_FORMAT'>PDF</argument>
       <resourceDescriptor name='' wsType='' uriString='/reports/samples/AllAccounts'     isNew='false'>
       <label></label>
     </resourceDescriptor>
      </request>
     ]]>
     </requestXmlString>"
 end
 send_data result.http.raw_body, :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => 'report.pdf', :disposition => 'attachment'
rescue Exception => e
  logger.error "SOAP Error: #{e}"
end
```

Comment: Hi Chaarel... Your answer is related with jasperserver. This problem was different.It was related with an old wiki page on wiki.rubyonrails.org including an adapter interface solution on ruby + java system call to generate reports.